# Is there a better way to "foreach" this upsert in SQLite3?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, optimization

I'm trying to upsert a number of different values, wherein the actual query is extremely similar between calls:

```sql
INSERT INTO `station` (`id`, `is_mirrored`) VALUES ('station1', TRUE) ON CONFLICT(`id`) DO UPDATE SET `is_mirrored`=TRUE;
INSERT INTO `station` (`id`, `is_mirrored`) VALUES ('station2', TRUE) ON CONFLICT(`id`) DO UPDATE SET `is_mirrored`=TRUE;
INSERT INTO `station` (`id`, `is_mirrored`) VALUES ('station3', TRUE) ON CONFLICT(`id`) DO UPDATE SET `is_mirrored`=TRUE;
INSERT INTO `station` (`id`, `is_mirrored`) VALUES ('station4', TRUE) ON CONFLICT(`id`) DO UPDATE SET `is_mirrored`=TRUE;
```

Ideally, I'd love to create a comma-separated list of `station.id` values that I can run this repetitive query to simplify it. If it were a simple `insert`, I could reduce the overhead, but it is not as clear to me with upsert logic how this might be done in SQLite3.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Please share sample what you have tried.

Comment: @User12345 I haven't really had any idea of what to try after about an hour of discovery, hence my post here. The only thing close is a bulk-insert statement, but that doesn't allow for the upsert functionality I'm trying to replicate.  I've looked into how I can possibly do for loops (which seems to work on number ranges, not foreach values), any prepared statement support (none), functions, etc. Some seemed to lead me down a path that is close, which is why I think there's an advanced technique I might be missing, but nothing I have been able to identify. It also may simply be impossible.

Answer (score -2):

This is a way to do loops in SQL

```
SELECT 
IDENTITY(int,1,1) as MYID,
value as StationID 
INTO #StationList
FROM STRING_SPLIT('Station1,Station2,Station3,Station4', ',');

DECLARE @MYID INT
DECLARE @StationID VARCHAR(50)

SET @MYID = (SELECT MIN(MYID) FROM #StationList)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #StationList WHERE MYID=@MYID)
BEGIN
    SET @StationID = (Select StationID FROM #StationList WHERE MYID=@MYID)
    
    INSERT INTO station (id, is_mirrored) VALUES (@StationID, 'TRUE') ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET is_mirrored='TRUE';
    SET @MYID = @MYID + 1
END
```

The above query can be written in SQLite in this way:

```
WITH RECURSIVE vars AS (
    SELECT 'Station1,Station2,Station3,Station4' AS stationString
)
-- Create a temporary table to store the values
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StationList (
    MYID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    StationID TEXT
);

-- Insert values into the temporary table using the variable string
INSERT INTO StationList (StationID)
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(
        stationString,
        1 + LENGTH(SUBSTR(stationString, 1, INSTR(stationString, ',') - 1)),
        INSTR(stationString || ',', ',') - INSTR(stationString, ',') - 1
    )) AS StationID
FROM vars
JOIN sqlite_master; 

-- Declare variables 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CountVars (MYID INTEGER);
INSERT INTO CountVars VALUES (1);

-- Loop through the temporary table
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StationList WHERE MYID = (SELECT MYID FROM CountVars)) > 0 DO
    -- Get the StationID
    SELECT StationID INTO :StationID FROM StationList WHERE MYID = (SELECT MYID FROM CountVars);
    
    -- Your INSERT or UPDATE statement
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO station (id, is_mirrored) VALUES (:StationID, 'TRUE');

    -- Increment MYID
    UPDATE CountVars SET MYID = (SELECT MYID FROM CountVars) + 1;
END WHILE;

-- Drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS StationList;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CountVars;
```

Comment: @AndrewVaughan I guess because it uses what looks like syntax of MS SQL Server, which is not supported by SQLite?